# My 2004 Audi a4 is making a gurgling noise from my engine

Tags: troubleshooting, cooling-system, audi, coolant-leak

My 2004 Audi a4 is making a gurgling noise from my engine. I am also having to constantly put antifreeze in it. Is this related? I know I'll have to take her to be looked at but can anyone tell me what I am to expect to hear of the issue and cost?

Comment: Have you been able to spot any signs of coolant leaking out? How often do you need to add coolant?

Comment: Which engine does your car have? It seems very likely that the coolant loss and the gurgling go together.

Answer (score 1):

Open the hood a listen for where the gurgling is coming from:

- Find the water pump and listen there
- Listen near the radiator
- Listen near the coolant tank
- Listen near the top of the engine

Also, look for where your coolant is going:

- Look for puddles or stains where you usually park
- With the **engine off**, look near the belts for drops of liquid, stains, and spray marks (could be the water pump is leaking, if it is you need a new one)
- Look in front, behind and under the radiator for liquid, stains, and spray patterns
- Look at your two radiator hoses and squeeze them, see if it makes them leak (they need to be replaced if they leak)
- Look at the hoses coming from the water pump, squeeze them to see if it makes them leak (they need to be replaced if they leak)
- Look at your heater core hoses and squeeze them to see if it makes them leak (they need to be replaced if they leak)

Comment: I don't think this engine has an easily findable water pump – IIRC it is in the block with no hoses and driven by the timing belt. Leaks from the pump will be most noticeable around the bottom of the block on the right-hand side of the car, near the crankshaft sprocket for the timing belt.